# how to build arrays of objects in PHP without specifying an index number?

Tags: php, arrays, object

Here is a weird question. I am building an array of objects manually, like this:

```
$pages_array[0]->slug = "index";
$pages_array[0]->title = "Site Index";  
$pages_array[0]->template = "interior";

$pages_array[1]->slug = "a";
$pages_array[1]->title = "100% Wide (Layout A)";
$pages_array[1]->template = "interior";

$pages_array[2]->slug = "homepage";
$pages_array[2]->title = "Homepage";
$pages_array[2]->template = "homepage";
```

I like how clearcut this is, but because I have to specify the index number, I can't rearrange them easily. How can I do this without the index number? Related, what is a better way to do this?

I also tried writing this by making a class, and having each spot on the array be instances of that class. But since this is a configuration file, it was hard to read and know what argument went with what parameter. That's why I chose this old-school method above.

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: *(sidenote)* PHP has a native class for storing object collections with [`SplObjectStorage`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php). If you need the objects in a specific order, have a look at [`SplMaxHeap`](http://github.com/salathe/spl-examples/wiki/SplMaxHeap)

Comment: please clearify the question. What are you trying to achieve by "rearranging" and in general?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This code

```
 $pages_array[1]->slug = "a";
```

is invalid anyways - you'll get a "strict" warning if you don't initialize the object properly. So you have to construct an object somehow - either with a constructor:

```
 $pages_array[] = new MyObject('index', 'title'....)
```

or using a stdclass cast

```
 $pages_array[] = (object) array('slug' => 'xxx', 'title' => 'etc')
```

Comment: Hey, I did exactly this, getting a warning "PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in " How can I get around this ?

Comment: (object) array(...) this is what i looking for to make my code like a pro

Answer (score 18):

If you make them arrays with named keys rather than objects, you can do it like this:

```
$pages_array = array(
     array(
         'slug' => 'index',
         'title' => 'Site Index',
         'template' => 'interior'
     ),

     array(
         'slug' => 'a',
         'title' => '100% Wide (Layout A)',
         'template' => 'interior'
     ),

     array(
         'slug' => 'homepage',
         'title' => 'Homepage',
         'template' => 'homepage'
     )
);
```

You can combine this with Fanis' solution and use the slugs as the keys if you like.

Answer (score 11):

There are three ways:

Way 1 :

```
$pages_array=[
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "James"
    ],
    [
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => "Mary"
    ]

];
```

Way 2 :

```
 $pages_array[0] =
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "James"
    ];
 $pages_array[1] = 
    [
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => "Mary"
    ];
```

Way 3 :

```
$pages_array = array(
    array(
      "id" => 2,
      "name" => "Mary"
    ),

    array(
      "id" => 1,
      "name" => "James"
    ),
   
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're not setting any `$pages_array` elements elsewhere, you can set a simple variable.

```
$i = 0;

$pages_array[$i]->slug = "index";
$pages_array[$i]->title = "Site Index";  
$pages_array[$i]->template = "interior";
$i++;

$pages_array[$i]->slug = "a";
$pages_array[$i]->title = "100% Wide (Layout A)";
$pages_array[$i]->template = "interior";
$i++;

$pages_array[$i]->slug = "homepage";
$pages_array[$i]->title = "Homepage";
$pages_array[$i]->template = "homepage";
$i++;
```

You just have to remember to increment `$i` every time so you don't overwrite an element.

Comment: These are all awesome ideas, thanks everybody!  Object casting and using a variable for the index are both great, simple solutions to my problem, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the slug will be unique, perhaps use it to identify your page arrays:

```
$pages_array = array() ;

$pages_array['index'] = array() ;
$pages_array['index']['title'] = 'Site Index' ;
$pages_array['index']['template'] = 'interior' ;

$pages_array['a'] = array() ;
$pages_array['a']['title'] = '100% Wide (Layout A)' ;
$pages_array['a']['template'] = 'interior' ;
```

etc

You'll just need to use the array key to get your slug value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain sequence indexes. May be this will help.

```
$pages_array[]->slug = "index";
$key = array_search(end($pages_array),$pages_array );
$pages_array[$key]->title = "Site Index";  
$pages_array[$key]->template = "interior";

$pages_array[]->slug = "a";
$key = array_search(end($pages_array),$pages_array );
$pages_array[$key]->title = "100% Wide (Layout A)";
$pages_array[$key]->template = "interior";

$pages_array[]->slug = "homepage";
$key = array_search(end($pages_array),$pages_array );
$pages_array[$key]->title = "Homepage";
$pages_array[$key]->template = "homepage";
```

[Check](http://codepad.org/zK6so58t)