# Php doing a for loop with OOP,can't figure out how

Tags: php, for-loop

i have this code below:

```
   <?php
    class Product {
        public $name;
        public $desc;
        public $price;
        public $category;
        public $qty;
        public $model;
        public $manufacturer;

        function display() {
            $output = '';

            $output .= $this->name ."</br>";
            $output .= $this->desc . "</br>";
            $output .= $this->price "</br>";
            $output .= $this->category "</br>";
            $output .= $this->qty "</br>";
            $output .= $this->model "</br>";
            $output .= $this->manufacturer "</br>";


            return $output;
        }
    }


    $product = new Product();
    $product->name = "Samsung galaxy s6";
    $product->desc = "It's kind of good but meh";
    $product->price = "1000 GBP";
    $product->category = "Phones";
    $product->qty = "Quantity:999";
    $product->model = "Samsung s6";
    $product->manufacturer = "Phone guys";

    echo $product->display();

    ?>
```

So this function works without a problem by itself when i set the values in:

```
$product->name = "Samsung galaxy s6";
$product->desc = "It's kind of good but meh";
$product->price = "1000 GBP";
$product->category = "Phones";
$product->qty = "Quantity:999";
$product->model = "Samsung s6";
$product->manufacturer = "Phone guys";
```

So when i set all the values everything works,but my question is: Is it possible for me to make each one of those an array lets say i want to display 2 products in the browser

When I set the $product->name to $product->name = array("Samsubg","Iphone","Apple");

This by itself displays only **Apple* and i kind of get lost here on what to do

Thanks.

Comment: You could create an array of objects maybe ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612190/array-of-php-objects

Comment: Then you can iterate through that array and call the function for each object. You might have to make some changes to your code though.

Comment: Just make an array of objects; don't try to make the object store arrays where it should store scalars.

Comment: @Maximus2012 is there another way of doing this since i have to add like lets say 100 different products?

Comment: I think you should look into creating a constructor of the class and initiate the values for each product at the time of creating an object of that class. Then you can combine that logic with the array of objects approach. That should simplify things a bit.

Comment: It also depends on what you are trying to do here and what should be the end goal. Is there some sort of database involved here ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 no,just a php file and 100 variables of each element,and i want them to be displayed in a browser (to be able to see all 100 of them one after another) this is the end goal

Comment: In that case I would highly recommend that you add them to a database if possible. In that case you may not even need the class/object approach and just display the information using a simple database query. That approach will also be helpful in adding/removing values in the future.

Comment: @Maximus2012 Yeah,i guess that might be the best way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You normally would use a setter method to set variables and it would look like this if you wanted to set it as an array.

```
private name = array();

public function setName($name) {
    $this->name[] = $name;
}
```

You would want to do this with all your variables. If you wanted to pass in an array you could loop through it and pass one at a time or pass the whole array you would want to set your setter function like this:

```
private name = array();

public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
}
```

You could then set it by calling the method and passing in the array.

```
$product->setName($myArrayOfNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

With OOP, it doesn't make sense to have a single object with fields that are arrays. That is just procedural programming in an object.

Instead, the fields of each object should describe the state of only the object itself. If you need an array to describe multiple products, then you simply make an array of the `Product` object.

```
$products = array();

$product_one = new Product();
$product_one->name = "Samsung galaxy s6";
$product_one->desc = "It's kind of good but meh";
$product_one->price = "1000 GBP";
$product_one->category = "Phones";
$product_one->qty = "Quantity:999";
$product_one->model = "Samsung s6";
$product_one->manufacturer = "Phone guys";

$product_two = new Product();
$product_two->name = "iPhone6";
$product_two->desc = "who knows";
$product_two->price = "10000 GBP";
$product_two->category = "Phones";
$product_two->qty = "Quantity: 1";
$product_two->model = "iPhone";
$product_two->manufacturer = "Apple";

$products[] = $product_one;
$products[] = $product_two;

foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->display();
}
```

Comment: Yeah this could work,but my idea was to add 100 different products and than foreach them to display all of them in the browser

Comment: You can still do that with this approach but you would also need to type out the information about each product. This answer can also be further simplified using the constructor approach that I mentioned in the comments.

Comment: That depends entirely on how he is defining the products though. Is it from a database? is it parsed from a file? An array of name, desc, price, etc? Without more information, the only two options are a very long file or a very long constructor.

Comment: @Zsw please look at the comments that I added to the original question. Without the database, I think the only option is to type out everything much like your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Define your array property in the class, here is a full working example.

```
 class Body
{
   private $name = array();
  public function setName($name)
  {
    $this->name = $name;
  }
  public function getName()
  {
    return $this->name;
  }
}
$user = new Body();
$user->setName(array("Samsubg","Iphone","Apple"));
```

`echo var_dump($user->getName());` This will dump an array, all you have to do is do a `for` loop over it or get the array values by index: `$user->getName[0]`.