# PHP Object with array of objects finding key/value and linking it with another key/value pair

Tags: php, object, multidimensional-array, key, coinbase-php

**PROGRESS:** Almost there... Need help on the last bit!!!

```
$users = $client->getAccounts();


$num = count($users);
for ( $x=0; $x < $num; $x++){
    foreach($users[$x] as $y => $y_value) {
        if($y_value == iLy){
            print_r($y);
            echo '<br>';
            print_r($x);
            echo '<br>';
            print_r($user[$x]["id"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the latest bit of code I have written and I have been to locate the array value or the array I am looking for by search by name. `print_r($user[$x]["id"]);`

Results in:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in /home/examplesite/BLANK.com/CBapi.php on line 37
```

I used this simplification to discover the logic for my solution:
**This works**

```
<?php
$age = array (array("name"=>"iLy", "id"=>"37", "balance"=>"43"),
              array("name"=>"jim", "id"=>"67", "balance"=>"47"));

echo $age[0]['id'];

$num = count($age);
for ( $x=0; $x < $num; $x++){
    foreach($age[$x] as $y => $y_value) {
        if($y_value == 43){
            print_r($y);
            echo '<br>';
            print_r($x);
            echo '<br>';
            print_r($age[$x]["id"]);

        }
    }
}
?>
```

I believe I am just calling the wrong Key Name. 
++++++++++++++++++++++ **Original Post Below** ++++++++++++++++++++++

Current code:

```
$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$configuration->setApiUrl(Configuration::SANDBOX_API_URL); 
$client = Client::create($configuration);

$users = $client->getAccounts();
```

I have been struggling with this for four days now... I used function below and it returns an object which contains an array of objects. My goal is to search through the collection of objects for a key and value, (For example to search the name of a current user:`$currentuser = 'iLy'; $user = $currentuser;` Then I could identify the array value, which would be  `$users[2]` for our example 'iLy' to search the key value 'id', to get the $accountId.

Ideally I could search 'name' => iLy and have it return the 'id' => 'xxxxxxx' in that same array.

When I create accounts this is the only way I have been able to figure out how to get the accountID, and I haven't found any other API calls to get the account by name. I have only been able to isolate one object using `$users[2]`. I know this may be a repeat post, but I haven't been able to make any of the other solutions work.
[PHP - find entry by object property from a array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742903/php-find-entry-by-object-property-from-a-array-of-objects) , [Array of PHP Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612190/array-of-php-objects/8612289)

Maybe I am using the wrong solutions or applying them wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public function getAccounts(array $params = [])
{
    return $this->getAndMapCollection('/v2/accounts',$params,'toAccounts');                           
}
```

Returns this:

```html
    

Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\ResourceCollection Object (
[previousUri:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\ResourceCollection:private] =>
[nextUri:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\ResourceCollection:private] =>
[resources:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\ResourceCollection:private] => Array (
[0] => Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account Object (
[name:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => Jennaod3
[primary:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] =>
[type:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => wallet
[currency:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => BTC
[balance:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money Object (
[amount:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => 0.00000000
[currency:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => BTC
)
[nativeBalance:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money Object (
[amount:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => 0.00
[currency:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => USD
)
[createdAt:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => DateTime Object (
[date] => 2016-05-24 04:55:41.000000
[timezone_type] => 2
[timezone] => Z
)
[updatedAt:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => DateTime Object (
[date] => 2016-05-24 04:55:41.000000
[timezone_type] => 2
[timezone] => Z
)
[id:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => 0d41fc45-0a53-58cb-9931-c9a33f520963
[resource:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => account
[resourcePath:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => /v2/accounts/0d41fc45-0a53-58cb-9931-c9a33f520963
[rawData:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => Array (
[id] => 0d41fc45-0a53-58cb-9931-c9a33f520963
[name] => Jennaod3
[primary] =>
[type] => wallet
[currency] => BTC
[balance] => Array (
[amount] => 0.00000000
[currency] => BTC
)
[native_balance] => Array (
[amount] => 0.00
[currency] => USD
)
[created_at] => 2016-05-24T04:55:41Z
[updated_at] => 2016-05-24T04:55:41Z
[resource] => account
[resource_path] => /v2/accounts/0d41fc45-0a53-58cb-9931-c9a33f520963
)
)
[1] => Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account Object (
[name:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => jenna works to
[primary:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] =>
[type:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => wallet
[currency:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => BTC
[balance:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money Object (
[amount:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => 0.00000000
[currency:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => BTC
)
[nativeBalance:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money Object (
[amount:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => 0.00
[currency:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => USD
)
[createdAt:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => DateTime Object (
[date] => 2016-05-22 13:37:16.000000
[timezone_type] => 2
[timezone] => Z
)
[updatedAt:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => DateTime Object (
[date] => 2016-05-22 13:37:16.000000
[timezone_type] => 2
[timezone] => Z
)
[id:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => e7ab48b4-bc76-513a-a78b-6d627f32f848
[resource:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => account
[resourcePath:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => /v2/accounts/e7ab48b4-bc76-513a-a78b-6d627f32f848
[rawData:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => Array (
[id] => e7ab48b4-bc76-513a-a78b-6d627f32f848
[name] => jenna works to
[primary] =>
[type] => wallet
[currency] => BTC
[balance] => Array (
[amount] => 0.00000000
[currency] => BTC
)
[native_balance] => Array (
[amount] => 0.00
[currency] => USD
)
[created_at] => 2016-05-22T13:37:16Z
[updated_at] => 2016-05-22T13:37:16Z
[resource] => account
[resource_path] => /v2/accounts/e7ab48b4-bc76-513a-a78b-6d627f32f848
)
)
[2] => Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account Object (
[name:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => iLy
[primary:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] =>
[type:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => wallet
[currency:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => BTC
[balance:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money Object (
[amount:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => 0.00000000
[currency:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => BTC
)
[nativeBalance:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money Object (
[amount:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => 0.00
[currency:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => USD
)
[createdAt:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => DateTime Object (
[date] => 2016-05-22 13:33:36.000000
[timezone_type] => 2
[timezone] => Z
)
[updatedAt:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => DateTime Object (
[date] => 2016-05-22 13:33:36.000000
[timezone_type] => 2
[timezone] => Z
)
[id:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => c95fd701-cf2b-56f7-b438-9a2f0e61b21c
[resource:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => account
[resourcePath:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => /v2/accounts/c95fd701-cf2b-56f7-b438-9a2f0e61b21c
[rawData:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => Array (
[id] => c95fd701-cf2b-56f7-b438-9a2f0e61b21c
[name] => iLy
[primary] =>
[type] => wallet
[currency] => BTC
[balance] => Array (
[amount] => 0.00000000
[currency] => BTC
)
[native_balance] => Array (
[amount] => 0.00
[currency] => USD
)
[created_at] => 2016-05-22T13:33:36Z
[updated_at] => 2016-05-22T13:33:36Z
[resource] => account
[resource_path] => /v2/accounts/c95fd701-cf2b-56f7-b438-9a2f0e61b21c
)
)
[3] => Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account Object (
[name:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => BTC Wallet
[primary:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => 1
[type:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => wallet
[currency:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => BTC
[balance:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money Object (
[amount:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => 0.10000000
[currency:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => BTC
)
[nativeBalance:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money Object (
[amount:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => 1000.00
[currency:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Value\\Money:private] => USD
)
[createdAt:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => DateTime Object (
[date] => 2016-05-21 02:41:13.000000
[timezone_type] => 2
[timezone] => Z
)
[updatedAt:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Account:private] => DateTime Object (
[date] => 2016-05-21 02:41:14.000000
[timezone_type] => 2
[timezone] => Z
)
[id:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => 0e0dac44-6900-59e9-8183-99b9459d1205
[resource:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => account
[resourcePath:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => /v2/accounts/0e0dac44-6900-59e9-8183-99b9459d1205
[rawData:Coinbase\\Wallet\\Resource\\Resource:private] => Array (
[id] => 0e0dac44-6900-59e9-8183-99b9459d1205
[name] => BTC Wallet
[primary] => 1
[type] => wallet
[currency] => BTC
[balance] => Array (
[amount] => 0.10000000
[currency] => BTC
)
[native_balance] => Array (
[amount] => 1000.00
[currency] => USD
)
[created_at] => 2016-05-21T02:41:13Z
[updated_at] => 2016-05-21T02:41:14Z
[resource] => account
[resource_path] => /v2/accounts/0e0dac44-6900-59e9-8183-99b9459d1205
)
)
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my answer and it isn't pretty. It turns out I had to make some of the variables public in the API resource file, which I'm not sure if that was a good idea, but it achieved my goal using this code:

```
$users = $client->getAccounts();

$num = count($users);

for ( $x=0; $x < $num; $x++){
    foreach($users[$x] as $y => $y_value) {
        if($y_value == iLy) {
            $bae = $users[$x];
            $account_id = '';
            foreach ($bae as $k => $k_value) {
                $account_id = $k_value;
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

It seems as though all my arrays were objects and the only way I could obtain the values I needed was by using foreach loops.