# How to create this array structure in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

I am trying to create an array structure like the initial one found here: [D3 JSON data conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912966/d3-json-data-conversion)

Mine would look something like the below, be dynamic, and then be passed to json_encode() to make a json object.

```
[
  { "name": "Table1", "lab": "name1", "cell": "c1", "avg": avgUsage1},
  { "name": "Table1", "lab": "name2", "cell": "c2", "avg": avgUsage2},
  { "name": "Table1", "lab": "name3", "cell": "c3", "avg": avgUsage3},
  { "name": "Table1", "lab": "name4", "cell": "c4", "avg": avgUsage4},
  { "name": "Table1", "lab": "name5", "cell": "c5", "avg": avgUsage5} ...
]
```

The problem is that I cannot have an array that has the same values for the key. What is this data structure and how can I create something like it to then create a nested structure (I will follow the linked post to create the nested structure)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you think there would be same keys. You would have a  multidimensional array in php that would look like:

```
$arr = array(
    array( "name"=> "Table1", "lab"=> "name1", "cell"=> "c1", "avg"=>$avgUsage1),
    array( "name"=> "Table2", "lab"=> "name2", "cell"=> "c2", "avg"=>$avgUsage2),
    //....
);
```

or each element could also be a `stdClass` object

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple mysql table values in the "avg" field to be displayed along with the avg? Something like: Value1, Value2..... AVG(Values)?

Comment: Thats the thing... Its for a d3 visualization. Each nest will mean something different. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317115/convert-flat-json-file-to-hierarchical-json-data-like-flare-json-d3-example-fil  So instead of this: { "dep": "First Top", "name": "First child", "model": "value1", "size": "320" }, I am looking for this: 
{"lab": "labname", "cell", "cell_name", "usage": Week1, Week2, Week3, Week4, Week5, Avg( Week1 +  Week2 +  Week3 +  Week4 + Week5) }.

Comment: that's not a valid javascript structure. Also note that it isn't what you asked in question either

Comment: I thought so. Ill see if I can concat the values as a string or something. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize it like that:

```
$arrayJSON = array(
    array(
        "name" => "Table1",
        "lab" => "name1",
        "cell" => "c1",
        "avg" => "avgUsage1"
    ),
    array(
    ....
    )
);
```

You can also make an array of class instances.

Comment: Array of class instances? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612190/array-of-php-objects Something like this?

Comment: @noc_coder like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#117149)