# How to create an array with objects in php

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I want to have an array with objects. For example.

```
public $aCarObjects = array();
$aCars = array('Audi','BMW','Ford');

foreach($aCars as $car){
  array_push($aCarObjects, new Car($car));
}

// Simplified class
class Car implements C{
   private $carName;

  public function __construct($carName){
     $this->carName = $carName;
  } 
}
interface C {}
```

This is a very shortened version of what I am trying. The class `Car` contains some info about the car.

When I am using the `Interface` `C` in the `Car` class. I cannot add objects to the array. Why is that so?

Comment: I found something that might help you -> [clik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612190/array-of-php-objects)
Even it's same example

Comment: Yes, you can use "new" inside array_push. A shorthand version (just a simpler syntax) is `$aCarObjects[] = new Car($car);`

Comment: Is there anything wrong with your code? Anything not working as expected?

Comment: @Jeff `array_push` isn't the same as `$array[]` - it only does the same thing in most cases

Comment: The word is `__construct` and not `__constructor` should that be what you're really using here; that makes your question unclear.

Comment: @Philipp Yes, I wasn't 100% precise.

Comment: Use modern syntax: $arrray[] replace array_push($array) since at least 4 years! It hurt to see

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped me find the problem. But not the solution yet. I've just updated my question.

Comment: This works: https://3v4l.org/85UdU What exactly happens when you run your code? Is there an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with arrays, it's a class hoisting bug (feature?) which is fixed by moving your class definition above the call to `new Car`. Apparently, PHP [does not hoist class definitions if they implement an interface](https://planetjon.ca/2014/06/28/php-class-hoisting-bug/).

Here's a minimal example of the phenomenon.

*Works:*

```
new Foo();
class Foo {}
interface Bar {}
```

*Doesn't:*

```
new Foo(); # <-- error: Class 'Foo' not found
class Foo implements Bar {}
interface Bar {}
```

Perhaps this is a candidate for [PHP Sadness](http://phpsadness.com/)?

Here's a working version of your code that also addresses a stray `public` keyword in line 1:

```
interface C {}

class Car implements C {
    private $carName;

    public function __construct($carName) {
        $this->carName = $carName;
    }
}

$aCarObjects = [];
$aCars = ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Ford'];

foreach ($aCars as $car) {
    array_push($aCarObjects, new Car($car));
}

print_r($aCarObjects);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Car Object
        (
            [carName:Car:private] => Audi
        )

    [1] => Car Object
        (
            [carName:Car:private] => BMW
        )

    [2] => Car Object
        (
            [carName:Car:private] => Ford
        )

)
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/MajorGlitteringNaturaldocs)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The construct part was a typo the other things are nice to know. My problem is the interface, which I did not mention.

Comment: The issue is that you've declared the class after the call to `new Car`. Move the class definition to the top of your file; it's not hoisted if it implements an interface, which is pretty strange.

Comment: That was really it! Thanks so much for all the answers!