# Updating Batch Model by ID Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to batch update a table by an ID

Here's my model

```
  public function update_batch_studentextend_by_studentID($data, $id = NULL) {
   $this->db->update_batch($this->_table_name, $data, "studentID => $id");
    return $id;
}
```

But it shows this error

```
A Database Error Occurred
One or more rows submitted for batch updating is missing the specified index.
Filename: models/Studentextend_m.php
Line Number: 41
```

Controller:

```
        $post = $this->input->post();
                        for($i=0; $i < count($post['subject']); $i++) {
                            $studentExtendArray[] = array(
                                'studentID' => $studentID,
                                'subject' => $post['subject'][$i],
                                'subjectng' => $post['subjectng'][$i],
                                'subjectlg' => $post['subjectlg'][$i],
                                'subjectcre' => $post['subjectcre'][$i],
    
    
                            );
                                $this->db->update_batch('studentextend', $studentExtendArray, 'studentID');
```

Array output:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [studentID] => 97
        [subject] => 
        [subjectng] => 115
        [subjectlg] => A+
        [subjectcre] => 7.0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [studentID] => 97
        [subject] => 
        [subjectng] => 110
        [subjectlg] => B-
        [subjectcre] => 7.0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [studentID] => 97
        [subject] => 
        [subjectng] => 90
        [subjectlg] => C-
        [subjectcre] => 8.0
    ) )
```

What i'm trying to do is update multiple rows with respect of "studentID" column.

The array output is correct, different values for each row, except for the StudentID, because that's what im trying to update the info on. But in the table, it shows same values for the 3 arrays/rows.

Comment: 3rd parameter: *"studentID => $id"* what do you think this does? see [update_batch()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::update_batch)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Scott',
        'age' => 25,
        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Tom',
        'age' => 30,
        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    )
);

$this->db->update_batch('students', $data, 'id'); ?>
```

So your function does not need to pass in an id as it's in the $data, therefore if it all works, you can just get the ids from the $data as you already have them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ok it works but it's duplicating the values, So if i'm inserting 4 rows, each row should have a different value, but instead, it's sending the same value for the 4 rows.

Comment: see https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update_batch and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612190/array-of-php-objects the one Manuel Sansone posted..

Comment: Ok, I updated my question, and added the controller. i followed your code after reading the docs, and it's the same thing, still same output, same values for multiple rows.

Comment: so should it be 'studentID' => $post['studentID'][$i] as that id is unique per student?

Comment: Yes but it's fetching the studentID, when i update a student.

Comment: I updated my question with more info, and array output.

Comment: not sure why. one workaround is you could create a $tempArray[] = $studentExtendArray[]; then do update, then $studentExtendArray[] = $tempArray[];

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter 4.2

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Scott',
        'age' => 25,
        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Tom',
        'age' => 30,
        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    )
);

$db->table('students')->updateBatch($data, 'id'); 
?>
```