# How to convert an array item to a class in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, class

I am having a difficult time typecasting an array item to a class.  I am trying to retrieve an array of Student class from a function, but when doing that, the array item loses the functional of the class, like getter, setter and portieres. The following is example showcasing the problem.

```
  class student {
   private $studentID;
   private $studentName;

   function getStudentID() {
    return this - > $studentID;
   }

   function getStudentName() {
    return this - > $studentName;
   }

   function setStudentID($id) {
    return this - > $studentID = $id;
   }

   function setStudentName($name) {
    return this - > $studentName = $name;
   }
  }

  function StudentArray() {
   $studentList = array();

   for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $studentX = new Student();
    $studentX - > setStudentName('name'.$i);
    array_push($studentList, $studentX);
   }

   $studentList = StudentArray();

   foreach($studentList as $student) {
    echo $student - > getStudentName(); /* this is the error. Even the 
    intellisense does not work.  */
   }
```

In C#, we can define the return type of the function and variable type.
like:
    ```

```
   private List < student > GetStudents() {
    List < student > myList = new List < Student > ();
     .....
    return myList;
   }

   private void mains (string[] args){
   List <Student> studentList = GetStudents();
   foreach(student in studentList) {
    MessageBox.Show(student.GetName);
```

}
    ```

How `| Array<Student> $student = array(); |` can be don PHP?

Comment: this might help you `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707722/how-to-build-arrays-of-objects-in-php-without-specifying-an-index-number`

Comment: Thanks. With a little bit of tweaking, that answer solved my problem. I just created a constructor inside the student class with an optional parameter. So every time I want to typecast the array element to the class, I just send it to the constructor to do a little bit of setters. There, I get beck the class functionality, like getters and setters.